# Samsung SM-N910F - What firmware should I use and is there any danger in using a "branded" firmware?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I read a lot before posting here but everywhere I looked I could not get a straight answer for my question.

I have a rooted Samsung SM-N910F (Galaxy Note 4) currently running 5.1.1, N910FXXU1POK1 (Nordic, NEE), LMY47X.N910FXXU1POK1, factory unlocked. I wan't to upgrade to 6.0.1 and have found a lot of threads on how to do this.

However some sites are using United Kingdom (Vodafone) firmware and still saying that as long as the model is a Samsung SM-N910F there should be [no trouble updating](http://www.teamandroid.com/2016/05/12/how-to-install-galaxy-note-4-n910f-xxu1dpd3-android-6-0-1-marshmallow-official-firmware/2/).

Is this true? If I use a "branded" firmware, will it affect my phone if it is factory unlocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True, you just get a different batch of bloatware from that region. Been using European firmwares for many of my Samsung devices from various regions because generally they're cleaner.

And no matter what your final decision is, [SamMobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-N910F/) has you covered for firmwares from all around the world.